# How to run code to tear down an object on errors in python

Tags: python, exception

So, I'm building out a piece of infrastructure that deals with automatically spinning up instances, setting up security groups, etc...

Sometimes, when going through the development process, things break. The object that deals with everything throws an error part way through the instantiation process,or one of countless other errors. When this happens, I basically get saddled with a good amount of infrastructure sitting around.

The issue is that I don't know ahead of time when/where an error will be thrown. My question is then, is there any way to run some piece of tear down code in the case of any error? For example:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # set up ec2 instance
        raise SomeError()

    def __on_error__(self):
        # tear down ec2 instances
```

The one other constraint is that some of the tear down code will probably error, which is fine. Typically this happens when I try to tear down something that didn't actually get instantiated yet. Ideally anything within the `__on_error__` function would fail silently, but short of wrapping everything in a `try/except:pass` loop, I'm not sure how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks a little bit like you're doing some sort of resource management -- In that case a context manager is really nice:

```
class Foo(object):
  ...
  def __enter__(self):
    return self

  def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value,tb):
    if exc_type is not None:
      # exception occurred, do some exception handling specific cleanup.
      self.__on_error__()
```

Now you can use it as a context manager:

```
with Foo() as foo:
    ...
```

And when you get to the end of that suite of commands, the `__exit__` method will run.

Note that this doesn't help you if the exception is thrown in `Foo.__init__` as the context doesn't get entered until after `Foo.__enter__` returns.

Comment: Will the context immediately run exit if an error occurs in enter?

Comment: @SlaterTyranus - No.  The context gets entered _after_ `__enter__` returns.